# How to use Squid(Proxy and reverse proxy) with joomla

Tags: optimization, caching, proxy, joomla, squid

i want some optimization tips on **joomla** performance i used memcache but i dont now how to use **proxy and reverse proxy ()** with joomla please help 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about caching reverse proxy.

You do it just as with any other app: set up your webserver to listen on port 81, then set squid on the same machine, make it listen on 80 and forward to 81. If you're not hosting for customers, you can enable aggresive caching, otherwise you may have issues with customers updating their content but not seeing the changes on frontend.